# Selecting dataframe by comparing multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and want to select the rows where some columns have some specific value. For example, for one column I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subA': [54,98,70,91,38],
    'subB': [25,26,30,93,30],
    'subC': [43,89,56,50,48]})


a = df[df['subA'] == 70]
print(a)
```

The output was as follow:

```
     subA  subB  subC
   2    70    30    56
```

This is expected and totally understandable. Now I want to select the rows where first two columns have some specific value. For example I changed the code as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subA': [54,98,70,91,38],
    'subB': [25,26,30,93,30],
    'subC': [43,89,56,50,48]})

my_sub = ['subA', 'subB']
my_marks = [54, 25]


a = df[df[my_sub] == my_marks]
print(a)
```

I was expecting to see results like this:

```
    subA  subB  subC
 1    54    25    43
```

But instead the output is full of NaN values which is not clear to me:

```
     subA  subB  subC
0  54.0  25.0   NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

What I am missing here to have the desired output? I also tried .loc and iloc but those did not help.

Comment: whats wrong a simple boolean? `test = (df['subA'].eq(54) & df['subB'].eq(25))` then call `df[test]`

Comment: You can create dictionary by `d = dict(zip(my_sub, my_marks))` and then any solution form dupe.

Comment: @jezrael It not seems to duplicate directly to me. Using `dict` can be another solution but not duplicate.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani - ya, agree, better be less strict like more. Reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to make it possible boolean indexing

```
df[(df[my_sub] == my_marks).all(axis=1)]
   subA  subB  subC
0    54    25    43
```

Or using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and `all` as @ansev said

```
df[df[my_sub].eq(my_marks).all(axis=1)]
   subA  subB  subC
0    54    25    43
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
df.loc[df.filter(my_sub).isin(my_marks).all(1)]
```

First step is to select only the interested columns, use the `isin` function to get booleans. The `all` function gets only rows where it is completely True, then you can index the original dataframe to get your result

```
       subA subB    subC
   0    54   25      43
```

Comment: I think this is clever, but i think OP needs a one to one relationship with the boolean i.e `SubA = 54` and `SuB = 25`